# Update Excel Cell Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to update an excel cell using asp.net web forms. Can anyone share a sample code?

Ex: Update A5 cell with 'test'

```
string sconnectionstring = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=d:\\examplefile.xlsx;extended properties=\"excel 12.0;hdr=yes;imex=1;maxscanrows=15;readonly=false\"";
OleDbConnection objconn = new OleDbConnection(sconnectionstring);
objconn.Open();
OleDbCommand objcmdselect = new OleDbCommand("update [Sheet1$A5:A5] set F1='test'", objconn);
objcmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: ...does that code not work or something?

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You may see if the following NuGet packages meet your needs: [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) or [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK). There may be others available. Also see [DocumentFormat.OpenXml Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1).  If you using DocumentFormat.OpenXml, you'll want to download/install the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools).